# Does it matter which commit the license file is added with?

Tags: github, license, license-file

Assuming I have a repo publicly available on GitHub with a license file, which covers some specific restrictions.

If the license file is added at a later stage of the project and the most of the past commits of the repo don't have it included, does the license terms extends to those commits as well OR such scenario makes all work available in the past commits unlicensed (or "default"-licensed by GitHub rules)?

How the same scenario works if I change the license later on (does it make different commits work under difference licenses)?